# Docker Add/Copy subdirectory separately

Tags: docker

I'm writing some code that will be run inside a Docker container. In order to test the code, I use an `ADD` line in the Dockerfile to include the folder containing it (say, `[build_root]/Dir`) to the Docker image. However, the only code I ever edit is in a subfolder (say `[build_root]/Dir/some/folders/Actual_code_dir`). The other stuff in `[build_root]/Dir` is really heavy (~4GB), so it's a pain to have to add it every time in the build stage just because I changed some lines in the code folders.

I would like to be able to `ADD` the `[build_root]/Dir` folder, but exclude the particular subfolder that contains the code; and then `ADD` that subfolder separately. That way, they would be in different intermediate layers of the image and different `docker build` commands would not require copying the entire 4GB of extra stuff.

How can I do this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is your host OS?